# quasar fiber returning empty results after the thread is started

Tags: spring-boot, rest, api-gateway, quasar, fibers

I am testing my POST endpoint locally on my spring boot application. I have a method that spawns a fiber thread to run a set of instructions that calls an endpoint A and my POST endpoint returns the results returned by A. However, when my POST request is completed, the results shown in postman is empty.
My code is as below

```
@RequestMapping("/prediction")
    public CustomResponse prediction(@RequestBody CustomRequest input, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return predictionClass.prediction(input);
    }

public CustomResponse prediction(CustomRequest input) {
        CustomResponse customResponse = new customResponse();
        new Fiber<CustomResponse>(new SuspendableRunnable() {

            public void  run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
                
                List<CustomRequest> inputs = new ArrayList<>();

                // A for loop is here to duplicate CustomRequest input parameter received and populate the inputs list
                
                List<CustomResponse> customResponses = inputs.stream()
                        .map(req -> processPrediction(req)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                for (CustomResponse x : customResponses) {
                    if (inputs.size() > 1) {
                        for (String outputKey : x.getOutputVars().keySet()) {
                            customResponse.getOutputVars().put(x.getModelName() + "_" + outputKey, x.getOutputVars().get(outputKey));
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Else statement will be run because the input is only size 1
                        customResponse.getOutputVars().putAll(x.getOutputVars());
                    
                }
                System.out.println(customResponse.getOutputVars().size());
            }
        }).start();
        return customResponse;

    }

    public CustomResponse processPrediction(CustomRequest input) {
        CustomResponse res = new CustomResponse();

        RestTemplate gzipRestTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .additionalInterceptors(new GzipHttpRequestInterceptor())
                .build();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(input, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = gzipRestTemplate.postForEntity("an-endpoint-url", entity, Map.class);

        Map<String, Object> outputs = (Map<String, Object>) responseEntity.getBody();

        res.getOutputVars().putAll(outputs);

        return res;

    }
```

In this test my input is only size 1, when I trigger the POST request using Postman, the `System.out.println(customResponse.getOutputVars().size());` returned 16 but on Postman it shows my outputVars is empty.

Interestingly I decided to do 2 experiments as below.

Experiment 1

```
public CustomResponse prediction() {
        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse ();
        new Fiber<Void>(new SuspendableRunnable() {

            public void  run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
                customResponse .setModelName("name");
                Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<>();
                test.put("pcd4Score", "hello");
                customResponse .getOutputVars().put("message", "hello");
            }
        }).start();
        return customResponse ;

    }
```

Postman returns customResponse with message and hello in it

Experiment 2

This experiment is the same as experiment 1 but with Thread.sleep(1000); I was thinking thread.sleep could represent `processPrediction` I have in my original code

```
public CustomResponse prediction() {
        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse ();
        new Fiber<Void>(new SuspendableRunnable() {

            public void  run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
                customResponse .setModelName("name");
                Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<>();
                test.put("pcd4Score", "hello");
                customResponse .getOutputVars().put("message", "hello");
            }
        }).start();
        return customResponse ;
    }
```

This time customResponse was empty and in my spring boot application terminal the error was

`[quasar] ERROR: while transforming {the-path-to-my-class-for-prediction-method}$1: Unable to instrument {the-path-to-my-class-for-prediction-method}$1#run()V because of blocking call to java/lang/Thread#sleep(J)V`

It feels like Experiment 1 was a success because the instructions wasn't as cpu intensive, I know I can code it in a way that I start the fiber in a separate method, and then only call `prediction` because it seems like postman returns in empty CustomResponse, then only the instructions inside `run()` started running, I just want to understand the behavior of Fiber. I have trouble googling for my situation (my google keywords were rest endpoint not returning results after a fiber thread is started) hence I am asking this on stackoverflow. I am also very new to the whole multithreading in java topic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding fiber join before `customResponse` is being returned like this. However it doesn't seem very elegant to have a try and catch just for .join(), is there a more elegant way to redo this whole method?

```
public CustomResponse prediction(CustomRequest input) {
        CustomResponse customResponse = new customResponse();
        Fiber fiber = new Fiber<CustomResponse>(new SuspendableRunnable() {

            public void  run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
                
                List<CustomRequest> inputs = new ArrayList<>();

                // A for loop is here to duplicate CustomRequest input parameter received and populate the inputs list
                
                List<CustomResponse> customResponses = inputs.stream()
                        .map(req -> processPrediction(req)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                for (CustomResponse x : customResponses) {
                    if (inputs.size() > 1) {
                        for (String outputKey : x.getOutputVars().keySet()) {
                            customResponse.getOutputVars().put(x.getModelName() + "_" + outputKey, x.getOutputVars().get(outputKey));
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Else statement will be run because the input is only size 1
                        customResponse.getOutputVars().putAll(x.getOutputVars());
                    
                }
                System.out.println(customResponse.getOutputVars().size());
            }
        }).start();
        try {
          fiber.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return customResponse;

    }
```